# SSRS 2008 R2 export to Excel leaves row one as blank

Tags: reporting-services, ssrs-2008, ssrs-grouping

In an SSRS 2008 R2 existing report, I want to change the report so the users have the option to hide headers when they export the report to excel. By allowing the users to hide headers when they export the SSRS 2008 report to excel, they can sort and filter the data. This avoids allowing excel to display an  error in a popup window saying there are merged cell.

My question is when I hide the headers and export the report to excel, there is a blank line in excel before the data and column headers appear.
Basically row # 1 in cell in blank and data and column headers show up starting in column #2.

Thus can you tell me how to remove the blank row in row #1 when the data is exported to excel?

Comment: Hi hide a header,column,textbox,etc is only a visual effect, if you can't see still this header,column,textbox,etc is occupying a space

Comment: How do you remove the space?

Comment: You can't remove that space as i told you if you can't see this header still is occupying a space

Answer (score 4):

I believe I have been able to duplicate your issue.  Be sure that there is no space between your table and the report header.  I find that setting the location property of the tablix to 0,0 is the best way to ensure that there is no space there.  By removing the space, you should get your tablix headers as the first row in excel.

Here's an article I wrote giving screen shots and step-by-step instructions.

http://jaysonseaverbi.blogspot.com/2013/11/ssrs-exporting-options-for-excel.html

Answer (score 1):

There could be another reason for the blank first row:
The existence of a page header in the report.
Solution: right-click on the grey area under the report and choose "Remove Page Header"
When exporting to Excel, the first row shows the headers (if existing)

Comment: awesome thanks, worked for me almost 1.5 years later!

Answer (score 0):

Use render format in an expression , to toggle the visiblity of the text box so the header appears empty

```
=iif(Globals!RenderFormat.Name = "EXCEL" ,  true, false
```

Note the EXCEL should be in caps for Excel 2003 (xls) and EXCELOPENXML for Excel 2007-2010 (xlsx) if using SQl 2012

Comment: When I want to hide the heading, I will also want to set the location of the tablix  to 0,0 as you recommended. Thus can you tell me or show me in code how to accomplish the following two tasks: 1. User want to hide header values? Place this is a parameter value? 2. In the same iif group of statement(s): a. hide the headers of the report, b. set the location of the tablix to 0,0 as you suggested

Answer (score -1):

Changing the tablix location to 0cm, 0cm , will fix the problem.